# Open bootstrap modal after failed submit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I got a login/register form in a modal. And after the submit failed and the page reloaded, I want to open the form again and add a second modal below the login modal.

My code doesn't work:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        /** @var \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable $Adapter */
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $data    = $form->getData();
            $Adapter = $this->authService->getAdapter();
            $Adapter
                ->setIdentity($data['email'])
                ->setCredential($data['password']);
            $authResult = $this->authService->authenticate();

            if (!$authResult->isValid())
            {
                echo "<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  alert('hi');
                });
                    </script >";
            }

            else
            {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute("blog");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return new ViewModel(
                [
                    'form' => $form,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: As of your not showing much code, can you please insert `alert('hi');` after your `<script>` tag? Does it alert you on page reload after invalid login?

Comment: @lippoliv alert doesn't work

Comment: So you know: Your PHP doesn't render the script. May you show us more of your PHP code so we could help you.

Comment: @lippoliv I added more code but I am not sure if this will help you

Comment: Your code is unreadable for sure. As of laravels routing, you don't have to check for post. Just add an POST-Routing, no GET-Routing and laravel will do the check for you.

Can you please replace your `echo` with an `dd` call to see if your PHP reach that line of code?

Comment: @lippoliv I don't use Laravel, I use Zendframework 2.

Comment: OK but you're doing an redirect, so your "echo" will not be visible... `return $this->redirect()->toRoute("blog");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of you're doing an redirect (`return $this->redirect()->toRoute("blog");`) to another route, your "echo" doesn't render. The new HTML of new Route will render.

So your echo has to be in the new route (may via an Parameter)